# console.log does not work inside pupeteer evaluate function

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Considering the following code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const run = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/pg/fotosdacurva/photos/?tab=albums', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log("ola");

        const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#content_container a'))
        return tds.map(td => td.textContent)
    });

    //console.log(data);
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

    await browser.close();
};

run();
```

`console.log` inside `page.evaluate()` function is not working and I cant figure out why? I think it might be related to async behavior. The function is being executed as the "data" variable is being set.

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that it runs `console.log` on *the actual page you open* so you don't see it. It's being run, just on the page you opened

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense Andrew!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to listen to console of the browser, you can simply use the console event of puppeteer. For example, check this example from their [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-console),

```
page.on('console', msg => {
  for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; ++i)
    console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
});
```

What it will do is, everytime there is a console message, a event will be triggered and it'll catch that event, and print the messages for you on your nodeJS console.

Just remember that if you print a dom element or array, the original browser console will print it properly however in nodeJS, you will probably see [object Object] or similar texts instead.

Comment: `msg.args()` is a function: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-consolemessage

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for console events on the page and then write to your own console:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', console.log);
```

It's not exactly the same as `console.log()` but it is helpful. It will give you output that looks like this:

```
ConsoleMessage {
  type: 'log',
  text: 'ola',
  args:
   [ JSHandle {
       _context: [Object],
       _client: [Object],
       _remoteObject: [Object],
       _disposed: false } ] }
```

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-console

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 you need to use `async await` to get args from `JSHandle` object. If you make `Promise.all(args)` and next time tries to evaluate on `executionContext` of `JSHandle` it will show the object of `consoleMessage`.

In this case, check my full answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/66801550/9026103